# Avoiding default interface implementation for @Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Let's say

- I have integration tests, therefore there is an `ApplicationContextIntegrationTests` class that contains dummy beans (dependencies on other services) for initializing the app context for integration profile like this:

```
 @Bean
 public MyService myService(Proc proc) {
       return new MyServiceImp();
 }
```

- I have an interface `MyInterfaceA` with 20 methods (the code is autogenerated based on the definition in `api.yaml`), I cannot implement it and I don't have access to the implementation. This interface (well, it is an implementation) also should be inserted in the application context. Obviously, I need to implement all interface methods in order to insert that bean and it leads to messy code with default methods implementations on 50 lines. Moreover, I need to insert 3 interfaces.

Is there a way to avoid that huge amount of code?

I have found that Lombok provides a `@Delegate` annotation which is used in similar situations, but it is appliable only on fields, whereas I need to deal with methods (bcs of `@Bean`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this generated class that implements `MyInterfaceA` also a bean? If so, you can use `@MockBean` to mock its implementation in the test. This way, wherever a bean of type `MyInterfaceA` is used, the mock will be injected in its place, and you can have the mock do whatever you want.